# How to instantiate in runtime a prefab in a given folder that is not within the Resources hierarchy?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a prefab let's say (MyPrefab.prefab) that is located as "Assets/Scripts/MyPrefab.prefab".

How can i instatiate it at runtime?

I tried this code snippet but it threw an excenption at run-time.

`var myGO = Instantiate(Resources.Load ("Assets/Scripts/MyPrefab") as GameObject);`

and this:

`var myGO = Instantiate(Resources.Load ("Assets/Scripts/MyPrefab.prefab") as GameObject);`

None of them worked for me. Unity threw an exception:
`ArgumentNullException: The Object you want to instantiate is null`

PS: I am not allowed to move the prefab to another folder.

Comment: One simple way is in the script that is in the heirachy you have a "gameobject" serialized field and then drop the prefab on that and it can access it, OR you can search by name in the assets.. But to use resources as Tenertni says it you need it in a folder called Resources (as documented by unity)

Answer (score 3):

In general [**Don't use Resources**](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7) at all!

If for some reason you still want to use it your assets **have to** be placed in a folder called `Resources` as only these are tracked by the [`Resources` system](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html)

> All assets that are in a folder named "Resources" anywhere in the Assets folder can be accessed via the Resources.Load functions. Multiple "Resources" folders may exist and when loading objects each will be examined.

---

But as said rather have a

```
public GameObject prefab;
```

or also

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject prefab;
```

field. This now appears in the [Inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingTheInspector.html) of according component. Simply drag&drop your prefab into this slot and then do

```
var myGo = Instantiate(prefab);
```

Especially have a look at [Instantiate Prefabs at runtime](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html)

Comment: Sorry if my questions seem stupid but i'm still struggling with Unity logic. What if i cannot reference my prefab in Unity? For example, if my class is not a sub-type of MonoBehaviour. All i want is calling the instantiate command from a regular c# method without all Unity stuff that constraints me to reference the GameObject by doing something in the Inspector. Is it possible?

Comment: @NabilAT possible maybe but what's the use of it? In the end it will almost in a all cases be a `MonoBehaviour` calling your method/using your non-MonoBehaviour class. It is hard to tell without seeing more of your code.. what is your exact usecase?

Answer (score 0):

To load something from the resources folder, it's path must have a `Resources` folder in it.

So your prefab could be

`Assets/Resources/Scripts/yourPrefabName` and then loaded by Resources API using

```
Resources.Load<GameObject>("Scripts/yourPrefabName");
```

Or

`Assets/Scripts/Resources/yourPrefabName` and then loaded by the resources API using

```
Resources.Load<GameObject>("yourPrefab");
```

PS: do not place scripts in a directory with a 'Resources' folder as it's direct or indirect parent.